# How to make buttons recognize "Drag" as "Click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, touch

I'm trying to make `buttons` with `Bootstrap 3` for `touch UI`.
My product is for people who are not familiar with touch devices, so users tend to press buttons "deeply".
When buttons are pressed deeply, a finger "position" on screen is slipped and browsers (like chrome) recognize buttons `dragged`.
When buttons start to be pressed, buttons are activated, but when `slipped`, buttons are deactivated and `click` is canceled.

What I want to do is making buttons that perform as `clicked` even if users press buttons with `slip`.

How can I do this?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kusamochi/ash7ou2r/10/) is my sample code.
Please look it on a touch device or a touch simulator on browser.

Comment: please post what you tried, only from your definition we can not help you

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/PdJDe/) is the example for a long press, this could help you.

Comment: @Vishalmodi I added my code. Thanks.

Comment: I think [Hammer.JS - Hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your helpful comments.
Finally I found the answer:

```js
const $touchButton = $(".touch-button");

$touchButton.on("mousedown touchstart", e => {
  const $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  $button.addClass("active");
});

$touchButton.on("touchmove", e => {
  const $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  $button.addClass("touch-button--touchmoving");
});

$touchButton.on("touchend", e => {
  const $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  $button.removeClass("active");
  if($button.hasClass("touch-button--touchmoving")) {
    $button.click();
    $button.removeClass("touch-button--touchmoving");
  }
});

$touchButton.on("mouseup", e => {
  const $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  $button.removeClass("active");
});

$touchButton.on("mouseleave", e => {
  const $button = $(e.currentTarget);
  $button.removeClass("active");
});

$touchButton.on("contextmenu", e => {
  return false;
});

$touchButton.on("click", e => {
  alert("世界一！");
});
```

```css
.touch-button {
  background-color: #169632;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 0px 0px rgba(13,87,30,1);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.touch-button.active {
  margin-top: 8px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px;
}

#my-button {
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="my-button" class="touch-button">日本の米は</button>
</div>
```